# JS: For loop creating null objects instead of skipping them outright

Tags: javascript, continue

I'm iterating over results pulled from a MySQL db and creating objects out of the results. I'm trying to skip over rows that have the same `election_id` as the previous row by using `continue`.

Instead of skipping that entire iteration, the code is resulting in a null object being created for that iteration.

```js
                    var elections = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        if (results[i-1] != null && results[i].election_id == results[i-1].election_id) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        elections[i] = {};
                        elections[i].electionID = results[i].election_id;
                        elections[i].date = results[i].date;
                        elections[i].type = results[i].type;
                        if (results[i].type == 'primary') {
                            elections[i].party = results[i].party_id;
                        }
                        elections[i].office = results[i].office_id;
                        if (results[i].district != null) {
                            elections[i].district = results[i].district;
                        }
                    }
```

Results look like this:

```js
153 
electionID 1531
date "2019-02-19T05:00:00.000Z"
type "special"
office "vahouse"
district 86

154 null

155 
electionID 1551
date "2019-06-11T04:00:00.000Z"
type "primary"
party "rep"
office "vahouse"
district 62

156 
electionID 1561
date "2019-06-11T04:00:00.000Z"
type "primary"
party "rep"
office "vasenate"
district 17

157 null

158 
electionID 1571
date "2019-06-11T04:00:00.000Z"
type "primary"
party "rep"
office "vahouse"
district 97
```

If I understand `continue` correctly, that should halt the iteration, increment `i` as if the iteration *had* completed, and then start the next iteration, therefore not creating an empty object. What gives?

Comment: When you skip `results[i]` you still increment `i`, so the next entry in the `elections` array will be at the next value of `i`. If `i` is 1 and it's the same as `results[0]`, then the next `elections` element to be filled in would be (at least) 2 and `elections[1]` is undefined.

Comment: You could move the `elections[i] = {};` statement to *before* the test.

Comment: results[i-1]   ? for i == 0 it can raise an error

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, I feel stupid for not realizing this. I replaced all elections[i] with elections[j] and incremented j at the end of the loop, which solves the problem of null objects.